# War deployment to JBoss from maven

Tags: jboss, maven-2, jboss7.x

I am having a pom file with specific properties to deploy to **jboss 7.10**. I am running on localhost and default ports. So I am using the **hard-deploy** instead of **deploy**. The mojo plugin was always copying the war to \server\standalone\deploy\standalone\deployments\ROOT.war for which I made a workaround.

```
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <jbossHome>C:\work\jboss-as-7.1.0.Final</jbossHome>
          <deploySubDir>..\..\..\standalone\deployments</deploySubDir>
          <serverName>standalone</serverName>
          <fileNames>
            <fileName>target/ROOT.war</fileName>
          </fileNames>
          <unpack>true</unpack>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

The **hard-undeploy** needs a different set of configuration than the **hard-deploy** goal. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use appropriate maven plugin with AS7

http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/7/plugins/maven/latest/